# How to deal with JavaScript Cannot read property error when the Div it is looking for is missing?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This simple JS/jQuery code below is causing this error on pages that do not have the item with that ID...

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'checked' of null`

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

        //Show or Hide Footer Call To Action Settings Metab Box
        if (document.getElementById('cta_show_yes').checked) {
            $('.showCta').show();
            $('.showCta').css('display','table-row');
        } else {
            $('.showCta').hide();
            $('.showCta').css('display','none');
        }
});
```

How can I make sure this error does not come up when the page is missing the item with the ID of **cta_show_yes** ?

Comment: Why are you mixing jQuery with raw Javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All jQuery version.

```
if ($('#cta_show_yes:checked').length > 0) 
    {
        $('.showCta').show().css('display','table-row');
    } else {
        $('.showCta').hide();
        // $('.showCta').css('display','none'); this is redudant to .hide()
    }
```

If the element doesn't exist, length will be 0. If length is greater than 0, then the element exists and [is checked](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/).

Answer (score 5):

Test to see if you get a (non-)null value before you try to access the property.

```
var element = document.getElementById('cta_show_yes');
if (element && element.checked) {
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check that element exists.

```
if($('#cta_show_yes').length){ 
    //Will execute if element exists

    //Show or Hide Footer Call To Action Settings Metab Box
    if ($('#cta_show_yes').prop('checked')) {
        $('.showCta').show();
        $('.showCta').css('display','table-row');
    } else {
        $('.showCta').hide();
        $('.showCta').css('display','none');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Though the other answers work, there is no need to look up that selector over and over and over...

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // Get it once
    var $showCta = $('.showCta');

    //Show or Hide Footer Call To Action Settings Metab Box
    if ($('#cta_show_yes').prop('checked')) {
        $showCta.show();
        $showCta.css('display','table-row');
    } else {
        $showCta.hide();
        $showCta.css('display','none');
    }
});
```

Comment: Yea, just caught that and was fixing it when the msg came in.

Comment: Don't forget that jQuery support [Method Chaining](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining) so sometimes selector lookups don't matter.

Answer (score -1):

Encapsulate your code in **try{} catch(err){}**
[w3schools documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_errors.asp)

Comment: And there ... goes your performance.  try/catch is major overkill.  It should be reserved for things that are truly unexpected.

Comment: This seems like an unexpected case to me.